# Are weak vector bosons produced in atomic transitions?

Tags: atomic-physics, weak-interaction

In [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/643787), I asked if gravitons could be produced in atomic transitions (an electron decaying to smaller energy orbitals). The energy taken away is astronomically small though. Can the same be said for W/Z particles? What about virtual W/Z particles? Can these produce neutrinos with an energy comparable to photons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th[e W nd Z bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons) have a mass of 80 and 91 GeV, giga ($10^9$) electron volt.  Atomic energies are of the order of electron volt, so they certainly cannot be produced. These large masses together with the smallness of the week coupling constant  do not even allow weak interactions to affect energy levels in atomic states.

Comment: What about neutrinos?

Comment: @Duepietri due to the week interaction neutrinow pass through matter as neutral without interacting uncles they happen with fermi on a nucleus, when there is a probability to interact with the quarks in the nucleons.

Comment: So they are produced?

Comment: @Duepietri  If a high energy particle, a muon or a proton hits a nucleon in the nucleus , yes neutrinos can be produced from the energy of the incoming particle in addtion with a dissolution of the nucleus. If a high energy neutrino gets close to a nucleon it may scatter off or generate more particles with its energy, through the weak interaction of neutrino with a quark

Comment: But what about the transition of the electron? If its state collapses to a lower energy state, can't a neutrino be produced? as the electron is surrounded by a virtual cloud of W's and Z's (as photons) why can't these be used to excite a neutrino?

Comment: because the large masses depress the propagator and the week coupling constant too is very very small compared to the electromagnetic. One has to study the mathematics to really  understand all this.